# Scroll past certain point AND screen's width within if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a function with jQuery that displays a `div` if the user scrolls past a certain point AND if the screen width is less than a certain number of pixels.

If both of these conditions are not met, I want the `div` to be hidden. This is what I have so far but I'm not sure how to make it work.

```js
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    
if ( (!$(y > 400)) && (!$($(window).width() < 400))  ){
        $('.subheader').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('.subheader').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
.subheader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subheader"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, fair warning this is horrible performance wise, so I suggest looking into throttling the function but it should fit your purposes. Basically what this does is on every scroll or window resize it checks your requirements and does what it should.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    subHeaderCheck();
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    subHeaderCheck();
  })

  function subHeaderCheck() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 20 && $(window).width() < 600) {
        $(".subheader").slideDown();
    } else {
        $(".subheader").slideUp();
    }
  }
})
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/calder12/rhje57a4/
Throttling: https://www.sitepoint.com/throttle-scroll-events/

Answer (score 0):

You should first fix your condition and make it a function. Then create two event listener to call the function one listener for window resize and one call when the page is scrolled